# Datatable JSON With Dynamic Array Names

Tags: javascript, php, json, datatables, transform

I am attempting to pull the below reference JSON into a Datatable. The problem I am having is that the data for each stock is within it's own array and the array names (tickers) are dynamic. In this example, there are only 3 stocks listed but the JSON will typically contain around 100.

I have been able to use the below script to display a single row by targeting a specific stock but since each stock is not an object but an array, I cannot simply type a 0 (ie. { "data": "**0**.quote.symbol" }) for each of the four columns to populate the table with all of the stocks in the JSON. Is there a way that I can reference the JSON in it's current form? If not, how do I transform it so that it is in an accessible format?

Thanks in advance!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#headlines-table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/php/rt.php',
            "dataSrc": "data",
        },
        "columns": [
        { "data": "AAPL.quote.symbol" },
        { "data": "AAPL.quote.latestPrice" },
        { "data": "AAPL.quote.latestVolume" },
        { "data": "AAPL.quote.avgTotalVolume" }
  ]
    } );
} );
```

JSON INPUT:

```
{"data":[{
"AAPL":{"quote":{"symbol":"AAPL","latestPrice":172.5,"latestVolume":17376726,"avgTotalVolume":33742427}},
"BA":{"quote":{"symbol":"BA","latestPrice":326.63,"latestVolume":3383911,"avgTotalVolume":6309861}},
"CA":{"quote":{"symbol":"CA","latestPrice":34.45,"latestVolume":1397950,"avgTotalVolume":2698759}}
}]}
```

rt.php:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?types=quote&filter=symbol,latestPrice,latestVolume,avgTotalVolume&symbols=aapl,ba,ca');
$data[data] = array(json_decode($json));
$obj = json_encode($data);
echo $obj;
```

Comment: Are you able to modify rt.php? IMO, I think it would be easier to return the right json structure from there instead of transforming it with javascript.

Comment: @nanocv I do have access to rt.php but I'm not able to change the JSON structure. Right now all rt.php does is take the JSON response from IEX and put it into the "data" object for datatables to read it. I have added the code for rt.php to the post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that your result is a kind of dictionary inside an arrays first item. You could sanitize the data in a `dataSrc` callback :

```
var table = $('#headlines-table').DataTable( {
  ajax: {
    url: '/php/rt.php',
    dataSrc: function(d) {
      var result = [];
      for (var prop in d.data[0]) {
        result.push(d.data[0][prop].quote);
      }
      return result;
    }
  },
  columns: [
    { data: "symbol" },
    { data: "latestPrice" },
    { data: "latestVolume" },
    { data: "avgTotalVolume" }
  ]
})
```

The above returns an array on the form

`[{ symbol: '..', latestPrice: '..' , latestVolume: '..', .. }, { .. }, ..]`

here is a demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2umtx1a7/**

Comment: A perfect elegant solution, simply articulated. Thank you!